# How can I make rounded TextField in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Material Design for iOS doesn't look good, especially the **TextField**. So is there any way to create your own ? Or Is ther any way to add some styling to TextField so it will look rounded ?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You can add rounded corners to a `TextField` within the decoration parameter of it

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    filled: true,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
    hintText: "Type in your text",
    fillColor: Colors.white70,
  ),
)
```

Comment: If you only want circular borders for Textfield use `BorderRadius.circular( )` instead of `BorderRadius.all( )`

Comment: any idea to change border color?

Answer (score 121):

@Rockvole answer is correct but just in case u don't like the **default border** around the `TextField`, you can achieve it by overriding the `borderSide` attribute of the `OutlineInputBorder` like this:

```
TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    controller: searchCtrl,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter a product name eg. pension',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 0, 
                style: BorderStyle.none,
            ),
        ),
        filled: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        fillColor: colorSearchBg,
    ),
),
```

Comment: You can also use Borderside.none

Answer (score 31):

You can get desired output with the help of `Container` Have a look..

```
new Container(
  child: new Text (
      "Text with rounded edges.",
      style: new TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue[500],
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900
      )
  ),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration (
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10.0)),
      color: Colors.black
  ),
  padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
),
```

Comment: Why not just `new EdgeInsets.all(16.0)`?  DRY!

Comment: Yes that will also work. @RandalSchwartz Question was about rounded TextField in flutter. That padding is an extra stuff.

Comment: Using an OutlineInputBorder it's a better solution, like pointed in other answers.

Comment: I agree with @siega. Using a container over a Textfield is an overkill. You can always use  OutlineInputBorder for that. Though you can use a container, when you want to have rounded fill color for textfiled.

Answer (score 13):

You can try this code bellow:

```
      decoration:  InputDecoration(
         border: OutlineInputBorder(
             borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                const Radius.circular(10.0), 
             ),
             borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 0, 
              style: BorderStyle.none,
              ),
             ),
           )
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I've collected this solution from several methods and solutions over the internet, it works very well with me, so it could help someone out there:
This solution will control the width and height of the `TextField`, and other properties

```
Container(
    child: Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(splashColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: false,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Color(0xFFbdc6cf)),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          hintText: 'Search',
          contentPadding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 0.0),


          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
          ),

          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),

    decoration: new BoxDecoration (
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(30.0)),
      color: Colors.white   ),   width: 250,   height: 50,   margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 210),   padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),

),
```

Answer (score 6):

You could approach the purpose in a few different ways:

First Approach:

```
Container(
      child: new Text (
          "Some Text",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black
          )
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration (
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(15)),
          color: Colors.white
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    ),
```

Second Approach:

```
 TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15.0),
            ),
          ),
          filled: true,
          hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
          hintText: "Hint text",
          fillColor: Colors.white),
    )
```

Third Approach:

```
TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    controller: someTextXontroller,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Hint Text',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 0, 
                style: BorderStyle.none,
            ),
        ),
        filled: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        fillColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
),
```

Comment: Nice, your third approach is the one that did it for me, but making that custom BorderSide. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this in `TextFormField`:

```dart
border: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
         Radius.circular(20.0),
     ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIconColor: Constants.appPrimaryColor,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        hintText: hintText,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        prefixIcon: prefixIcon != null
            ? Icon(
                prefixIcon,
                size: 20,
              )
            : null,
        suffixIcon: suffixIcon != null
            ? IconButton(
                onPressed: suffixIconTap,
                icon: Icon(
                  suffixIcon,
                  color: Constants.appPrimaryColor,
                  size: 20,
                ))
            : null,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
        ),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
```