# how can I create message textfield as in instagram using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, uitextfield

I am struggling to build text field on the bottom navigation bar like Instagram message

[image]

if there's anyone here who gonna help me to make this thing happen.
I m all ears if there s some question here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51543685/5407008 Try this

Comment: thank u bro, but it doesn't give me what i want

Answer (score 0):

I am Providing you one of the most easiest Documented, Plugin, which can be helpful in your case.

```
speech_bubble: ^0.0.9
```

Check this out, in this way, you can support the creator of the package. :cheers