# How to create specific text fields flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-design

How can i draw this text fields in flutter and add the text field inside?
Thank you[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make rounded TextField in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257641/how-can-i-make-rounded-textfield-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.purple),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Password",
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.purple,
              width: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Adding a gradient to the border seems pretty difficult. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395641/outlined-transparent-button-with-gradient-border-in-flutter) for more info.